# how to detect user clicked iOS remote notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

When user taps on a remote notification, the following callback is triggered in the app delegate:

`-application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`

in this scenario, application is launched and the app state is `UIApplicationStateActive` which I interpret it as user actioned on a remote notification.

**the problem:** 
This method can also get called when a remote notification arrives and app is in the foreground **with inactive state**.

***example***: when notification center view is open(swipe from top edge of screen down) or a UIAlert is open. In both case application state is `UIApplicationStateActive` and there is no way to tell whether it's a user actioned notification or system push received.

**Q**: How can I determine if `didReceiveRemoteNotification` callback is response to user tapping on remote notification vs arrival of remote notification?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
     if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
     { 
          //When your app is in foreground and it received a push notification
     }
     else if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) 
     {
          //When your app was in background and it received a push notification
     }
```

Also, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions will be called if the app was not running and the user tapped a notification. I have not tried it but i can assume you can get the notification details from options.

Comment: tx for the reply, it's a different problem. 

when app is in foreground and notification center is open, app is in Inactive state. Now when `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called, it can be 2 cases:
1-user action on a notification in notif center
2-arrival of new push notification. 

problem is that there is no way to distinguish this 2 scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To differentiate both calls in didReceiveRemoteNotification you can add this code from below.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
{


if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@“inactivePush" object:nil];


}

else if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState==UIApplicationStateActive){



    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"appOpenPush" object:nil];


}

//When the app is in the background
else {



}//End background

}

}
```